# Why are square Intergrable functions bounded? How is it related to L2 functions and Hilbert spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, hilbert-spaces, classical-mechanics, finite-element-method

To approximate the weak form of linear elliptic PDE to solve the Elasticity problem, we use L2 functions and Hilbert space. In that, I read that Square integrable functions are bounded. Why is that true and why boundedness is important here?

Comment: They aren't bounded, so hopefully it wasn't important.

Comment: Elements of $L^2$ are called 'square-integrable' (because the square of the (absolute value of the) function must have finite integral). And a-priori, it is definitely not true that these functions are bounded. Can you give a more exact quote?

Comment: their $L^2$ norms are bounded, maybe you heard that

Comment: Functions in $H^1$ over a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ are additionally continuous, which makes them bounded over compact domains.